# Change the background-image using jQuery and logical flow statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, background-image

My current project is creating a local weather app on codepen. I got the API from openweathermap.org and I'm using this code to get the users location:

```
 $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json",function(data2) {
     lat = data2.lat;
     long = data2.lon;
}
```

My goal is to have a different background image displayed based on the weather description from openweathermap.org. This I've given the variable weatherType.  I'm using if, if else and else statements to go through the different weatherTypes and assign a background image based on the weatherType that matches with the output. Also, all of my img's I got from unsplash.

For example, if the weatherType is rainy, I want to have a background photo of rain.

Here is an example of my code:

```
if (weatherType = "clear sky" || "few clouds" || "calm" || "light breeze" || 
"fresh breeze"){
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo- 
    1476611338391-6f395a0ebc7b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop= entropy&cs= 
    tinysrgb&s=e444d875e55debddc2319c386d96df90 )');
}

 else if (weatherType = "light intensity drizzle" || "drizzle   " || "heavy
 intensity drizzle" || "light intensity drizzle rain" || "drizzle rain" || 
 "heavy intensity drizzle rain" || "shower rain and drizzle" || "heavy shower 
 rain and drizzle" || "shower drizzle" || "light rain" || "moderate rain" ||
 "heavy intensity rain" || "very heavy rain" || "extreme rain" ||  "light
 intensity shower rain" || "shower rain" || "heavy intensity shower rain" ||
 "ragged shower rain" ){
    $("body").css("background-image",
    "url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470432581262-e7880e8fe79a?ixlib=rb
    -0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=c11591dd2cf9 c9d41b1d577df 
    052785)");
 }
```

My problem is the images don't seem to load, and instead I get this random photo instead, and that doesn't even always show up. I have also not focused on css or any form of style, as I'm trying to get this done first.

you can go to my codepen to look at the whole code: https://codepen.io/u1tron/pen/jVBeRq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement isn't valid.

- Use `===` for comparison instead of `=` which is for assignment
- Compare `weatherType` in each of your OR statements otherwise it's simply evaluating whether "shower rain" is true for example.

  if (weatherType === "clear sky" || weatherType === "few clouds"....

Alternatively you could use a `switch`:

```
switch(weatherType){
   case: "clear sky":
   case: "few clouds":
      //Set background image
      break;
   case "light intensity drizzle":
   case "drizzle   ":
      //Set different background image
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Assignment operator (=). Use conditional operator (==) in conditional statement. 
And Assign url value like:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + https://images.unsplash.com/photo- 
1476611338391-6f395a0ebc7b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop= entropy&cs= 
tinysrgb&s=e444d875e55debddc2319c386d96df90 + ')');
```

or you can store url in variable:

```
var imgUrl = https://images.unsplash.com/photo- 
1476611338391-6f395a0ebc7b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop= entropy&cs= 
tinysrgb&s=e444d875e55debddc2319c386d96df90 ;
$('body').css('background-image', 'url('+imgUrl +')');
```

Comment: I don't think you can have URLs in your code like that, without wrapping them in quotes. You don't need the quotes inside CSS's `url()` but you do need them in JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Curt explained the bad if syntax, but I want to add some advice:

Separate data and logic, like this

```
var images = [
{
    // default
    url: '1432071315934-33a387ee0437?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=3c71ae1096b49e93615f91a1319bddc9'
},
{
    condition: ['clear sky', 'few clouds', 'calm', 'light breeze', 'fresh breeze'],
    url: '1476611338391-6f395a0ebc7b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=e444d875e55debddc2319c386d96df90'
},
{
    condition:  ['light intensity drizzle', 'drizzle', 'heavy intensity drizzle', 'light intensity drizzle rain', 'drizzle rain', 'heavy intensity drizzle rain', 'shower rain and drizzle', 'heavy shower rain and drizzle', 'shower drizzle', 'light rain', 'moderate rain', 'heavy intensity rain', 'very heavy rain', 'extreme rain', 'light intensity shower rain', 'shower rain', 'heavy intensity shower rain', 'ragged shower rain'],
    url: '1470432581262-e7880e8fe79a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=c11591dd2cf9c9d491b1d577df052785'
}];
```

Later, in your setup function:

```
// background
var url;
for (var i in images) {
    if (!images[i]["condition"] || images[i]["condition"].indexOf(weatherType) > -1) {
        url = images[i]["url"];
    }
}
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-' + url + ')');
```